# Is there any way to handle security check on uploaded files

Tags: go, security, upload

I have a web application written with Go. It's easy to create an API endpoint to handle file uploads but I realized that we are trusting users to uploaded files is secure. These files might include viruses or anything else that can attack to server.

Are there any security measurements that I can take?

Comment: This depends on what you are planning to do with the uploaded files.

Comment: I am working for a legal-tech company. Sometimes when a user creates an order, we have to ask for some files and users should upload them. Admins will download these files and use them for legal purposes.

Comment: You can quarantine all such uploaded files in a separate directory or db, and move them to a permanent location once it is scanned.

Comment: What do you recommend for scanning?